# Access denied while accessing files in c:\Programdata in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am designing an command line application for  Windows 10 that require to replace some files in `c:\programdata` folder. But when I use `File.Copy` or `File.Move`, it throws an exception as:

> Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\***' is denied.

I have added `app.manifest` with `requireAdministrator` but it doesn't work.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have permissions on that folder. e.g. Right Click on folder > Properties > go to Security tab, and check if you have permissions. Also try your application by right click and 'Run as Administrator'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the user identity the actually runs the process/execute file.

This user should by "System" to have permissions to Move/Copy files on the Disk.

In debug mode you can always check the Task Manager => Processes and see the User Name for your process.

Comment: It runs under my username and not system. Is it possible run my application with elevate permission to carry out this operation?

Comment: Yes. For example, if this application will run from the Task Scheduler you can specify the user that will run it, same goes for Service (from Services.msc). If you will run it from a web site it'll take the web application pool user identity from it.

Comment: You don't need to run as local system just to write files to ProgramData!